# ‘QSqlDatabase’ was not declared

Tags: sql, qt4

I am very new to using QT4.  I am trying to use sql in an already working application.  However, when I try to compile I get this error:
"‘QSqlDatabase’ was not declared in this scope."

Here is the relevent code:

```
#include <QtSql>
QSqlDatabase db = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QMYSQL");

 db.setHostName("bigblue");
 db.setDatabaseName("flightdb");
 db.setUserName("acarlson");
 db.setPassword("1uTbSbAs");
 bool ok = db.open();
```

I have added QT += sql to my .pro file.

The code above it literally copied from here:http://qt.nokia.com/doc/4.5/qtsql.html

Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Or if anyone has a decent tutorial on this that would also be helpful. I just cant seem to find good docs

Comment: It also says,  error: QtSql: No such file or directory

Comment: If it's not finding QtSql it looks like a problem with your Qt installation

Comment: I have these packages installed:
libqt4-core
libqt4-debug
libqt4-gui
libqt4-qt3support
libqt4-sql
qt4-designer
qt4-dev-tools
qt4-doc
qt4-qtconfig

What do you think I am missing?

Comment: What compiler command line does make produce? Your code compiles ok for me

Comment: I am not sure what you mean.  Did you want screen output from the make file?

Comment: no the command line. It should look something like: g++ -c -pipe -O2 -march=k8 -pipe -Wall -W -D_REENTRANT -DQT_NO_DEBUG -DQT_SQL_LIB -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -DQT_SHARED -I/usr/share/qt4/mkspecs/linux-g++ -I. -I/usr/include/qt4/QtCore -I/usr/include/qt4/QtGui -I/usr/include/qt4/QtSql -I/usr/include/qt4 -I. -I. -o test.o test.cpp

Comment: Update project (qmake mainGui2.pro)...
Build (make)...
g++ -c -pipe -g -Wall -W -D_REENTRANT -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -DQT_SHARED -I/usr/share/qt4/mkspecs/linux-g++ -I. -I/usr/include/qt4/QtCore -I/usr/include/qt4/QtGui -I/usr/include/qt4 -Ibuild -Ibuild -o build/mainwindowimpl.o src/mainwindowimpl.cpp
src/mainwindowimpl.cpp:8:17:

Comment: qmake is not adding the path to the QtSql include files for some reason. Try rerunning qmake. Otherwise you can add -I/usr/include/qt4/QtSql to the CFLAGS in the Makefile

Comment: I just found the solution.  If not for you I wouldn't have got this working.  If I give you the solution, would you like to post it for credit?

Answer (score 5):

Ok, the problem was with my .pro file.  This is the file that gave me the error:

```
TEMPLATE = app
QT += sql
QT = gui core
CONFIG += qt debug warn_on console
DESTDIR = bin
OBJECTS_DIR = build
MOC_DIR = build
UI_DIR = build
FORMS = ui/mainwindow.ui ui/dialog.ui ui/dialog_con.ui ui/add_ingredient.ui
HEADERS = src/mainwindowimpl.h \
src/dialogimpl.h \
src/utils.h \
SOURCES = src/mainwindowimpl.cpp \
src/main.cpp \
src/dialogimpl.cpp \
src/utils.cpp \
```

The problem was that QT=gui core was overriding my QT+=sql. by moving the QT+=sql to bo right above HEADERS, it compiled just fine.  Thanks for the help.

Comment: I think that usually you shouldn't assign (with = )variables on a qmake file, but is better to add or remove values from them (with += or -=), or you can have some side effects as it happened to you.

Answer (score 2):

The compiler can't find the `QtSql` header and therefore doesn't know about `QSqlDatabase`. The header is in the QtSql subdirectory, so maybe you need to explicitly specify this in the include line:

```
#include <QtSql/QtSql>
```

Alternatively you have to make sure that the `QtSql` directory is in the include file search path of your compiler.

Comment: That just made it go from 3 errors, to 10.  Do you want me to post them all?

Comment: Usually the first error is the most significant one... What does the first error message say?

Answer (score -1):

I think you just need a

```
#include <QSqlDatabase>
```

as this is not automatically included by `QtSql`.

Comment: Just tried it, here are the new errors.


error: QtSql: No such file or directory
src/mainwindowimpl.cpp:9:24: error: QSqlDatabase: No such file or directory
src/mainwindowimpl.cpp: In member function ‘void MainWindowImpl::not_done()’:
src/mainwindowimpl.cpp:58: error: ‘QSqlDatabase’ was not declared in this scope
src/mainwindowimpl.cpp:58: error: expected `;' before ‘db’
src/mainwindowimpl.cpp:59: error: ‘db’ was not declared in this scope
src/mainwindowimpl.cpp:63: warning: unused variable ‘ok’

Comment: "I'm right, you're wrong" doesn't tend to make be trust you any more than the other person.  Any supporting evidence for your statement?

Comment: @Dems /usr/include/qt4/QtSql/QtSql contains the line:
#include "qsqldatabase.h"
Is that enough evidence?